# what does it mean to convert octet strings to nonnegative integers in RSA?

Tags: string, cryptography

I am trying to implement RSA PKCS #1 based on this spec
http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/pkcs/files/h11300-wp-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard.pdf

However, I am not sure what the purpose of OS2IP is in page 9. Assume my message is integer 258 and private key is e. Also assume we don't do any other formatting besides OS2IP.

So I will convert the 258 into octet strings and store it into char buf[2] = {0x02, 0x01}. Now before I compute the exponentiation 258^e. I need to call OS2IP to reverse the byte order and save it to buf_new[2] = {0x01, 0x02}. Now 0x0102 = 258.

However, if I initially stored 258 as buf[2] = {0x01, 0x02}. Then there is no need to call OS2IP, correct? or is this the convention that I have to save it into {0x02, 0x01}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS2IP encodes an non negative integer into it's **big endian** representation.

> However, if I initially stored 258 as buf[2] = {0x01, 0x02}. Then there is no need to call OS2IP, correct?

That is correct. 258 is already encoded in big endian although depending the length you choosed (!=2) you might be missing the leading zeros.

> or is this the convention that I have to save it into {0x02, 0x01}?

I don't understand your question :/

Comment: So that means the only reason we call OS2IP is we have a message encoded in small endian and we want to convert it to big endian?

Comment: Well PKCS defines how unsigned integers are encoded in order to allow implementations to work together regardless of their endianess (Think of the network byte order). The reason you want to call OS2IP is when your PKCS implementation will be executed on a little endian platform, on a big endian system you can simply read the octets from the memory hence OS2IP and I2OSP will most likely be no-op.